# SignalR: Wait for connection to be re-established before invoking methods

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

I have a HubProxy with many client triggered methods as described below:

```
proxy.invoke('hub_Subscribe');
proxy.invoke('triggerOnServer');
proxy.invoke('dataToServer',someModel);
```

Now if signalr is **not** connected to server and I try to invoke any of the above methods, it would give me `Connection must be started before data can be sent.` or `Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received.` error.

I am aware that one can utilize `connection.stateChanged` to confirm whether signalR is connected or not and invoke methods accordingly. But there is a need to log these events so that they can be invoked once signalr connection is up.

So, is there a simple way to log these methods in case the connection is disconnected? And later once the signalR connection is up and running, invoke those methods?

Something like `proxy.invoke('dataToServer',someModel).WaitForSignalRToBeConnected();`

**Note:** I continuously connect to server after client gets disconnected using [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20688130/3955513)

Comment: There is nothing in the SignalR client like `WaitForSignalRToBeConnected`. I think you are going to need maintain a message queue yourself.

Comment: I hope SignalR team would consider it for Version 3

Answer (score 0):

What you need are promises using the `$q` service.

I'm assuming you have to initialize the hub connection first, then invoke all three other methods in that order.

Create a service if you dont already have one for managing communication with the signalR server. Inject the `$q` service and signalR in it.

Wrap each of the following commands in seperate methods:

```
function doInitialize() {
    ... // connect to signalR
    return $q.when(connection.hub.start());
};

function doHubSubscribe() {
    return $q.when(proxy.invoke('hub_Subscribe'));
};

function doTriggerOnServer() {
    return $q.when(proxy.invoke('triggerOnServer'));
};

function doDataToServer() {
    return $q.when(proxy.invoke('dataToServer',someModel));
};
```

Now from your controller you can make nested calls to the service's methods in a way that the first one needs to pass in order for the next ones to run:

```
function initSignalR() {
    return service.doInitialize().then(function () {
        return service.doHubSubscribe();
    }).then(function () {
        return service.doTriggerOnServer();
    }).then(function () {
        return service.doDataToServer();
    })
};
```

**Edit:**

If you want to add more handling to your invokations, you can use the jQuery `.done()` and `.fail()` methods like this:

```
function sendDataToServer() {
    $q.when(proxy.invoke('dataToServer', someModel))
                    .done(function (result) {
                          deferred.resolve(result);
                          console.log('success!');
                      })
                      .fail(function () {
                          deferred.reject();
                          console.error('Error invoking server!');
                      }));
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

You can add more handling code to the `.fail()` method, like for example add the `$timeout` service to set retries.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is alright. The question is specifically for what happens once the connection is established and then the connection turns bad? During this time methods make be invoked by client. Methods invoked during disconnection needs to be handled in such a way that they are called again, once signalR connection is up.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have this problem solved with the following promise:

```
function GetOpenConnection() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const msMax = 1000;
        const msInc = 10;

        var ms = 0;

        var idInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (connection.connectionState == 1) {
                clearInterval(idInterval);
                resolve(connection);
            }
            
            ms += msInc;

            if (ms >= msMax) {
                clearInterval(idInterval);
                reject(connection);
            }
        }, msInc);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
console.log('before GetOpenConnection()');
GetOpenConnection().then((connection) => {
    console.log('Connected: ', connection.connectionState);
    // invoke functions here
}).catch((connection) => {
    console.log('Not connected: ', connection.connectionState);
});
console.log('after GetOpenConnection()');
```